# Pronunciation of "are"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, spoken-english, american-accent, word-stress

In these sentences below, can I pronounce the "are"s as /ər/ instead of /ɑr/? I am talking about American English.

Sentences:

1) **"Problems of most people are not big."**

2) **"People who smoke cigarettes are gross."**

3) **"People who smoke are gross."**
(Note: Even though I don't like cigarettes, this is not my thought.)

4) **"People who hate me are deluded."**

For the people who don't know about phonetics: /ər/ is the sound you make when you pronounce the second syllable in "better", and /ɑr/ is the sound you make when you say the words like "car" and "far".

Comment: While you might hear some people pronounce it *ər* in some contexts, I wouldn't pronounce it like *er* as in *better* in any of those sentences.  Are you asking because you heard people say it that way, or just asking in general?

Comment: Thanks. I am asking in general. Because as far as I know, if we don't need to stress the word "are", we don't have to pronounce it as /ɑr/. But I was just not sure about the sentences like the ones I gave.

Comment: I'd nearly always use a neutral schwa instead of fully-enunciated ***are*** in all the examples above, ***and*** that would be the same schwa as the second syllable of ***better*** (usually ***beʔƏ***, since I'm a bit "Cockney").

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. You are British though. :) I wonder if the same thing can be done in American accent since I've been learning American English.

Comment: The first sentence is not grammatical. Car and far contain phonemes that are pronounced differently in BrE and AmE. American English speakers **do** pronounce "are" as /ər/ at times. "They er going" for "They are going".

Comment: Thanks. I know they do, but I am wondering about those sentences.

Comment: /ər/ is fast spoken AmE. for the others, you can listen to both here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/are There is also a fast spoken are in BrE, which is just a shortening of the regular one.

Comment: No, it is not just a shortening of it. The American and British "are" pronunciations are exactly the same except the pronunciation of the /r/ sound.

Answer (score 1):

As an American, we shorten "are" to /ər/ in fast spoken pronunciation.
But usually only if the final sound of the word before the "are" is a consonant sound.

I would pronounce these two sentences the same, if speaking quickly:

> Problems of most **people are** not big. => Problems of most **peopler** not big.

Notice how the "are" seems to attach itself to the end of the previous word. That flows easily pronunciation-wise in your examples 2 and 3 as well.

> People who smoke **cigarettes are** gross => People who smoke **cigaretteser** gross
>   People who **smoke are** gross => People who **smoker** gross

However, it doesn't flow as naturally and easily with your last example because the word before ends with a vowel sound, making it hard to attach the "are" as /ər/. If I try to say /ər/ after "me", I am forced to make it its own syllable, and since "are" should be pronounced /ar/, then that is how it gets pronounced in that sentence. It ends up taking more energy to force it to be pronounced as /ər/ in that situation.

> People who hate **me are** deluded.

(Note: The words "*peopler*", "*cigaretteser*", and "*smoker*" in the examples are meant only to show pronunciation, and are not examples of proper spelling or grammar)

Comment: so it is like the northern uk 't sound, shortening the whole phrase 'to the' to ' going tshops'

Answer (score -1):

North American English - /ar/ like car - is correct